# Prevent Direct URL input but grant Localhost access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

I am trying to write a .htaccess file for my website, which will prevent access to pages and images via direct URL input, but localhost requests will be granted. So far I've found this code after some googling:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(php|css|js|jpg)$ - [F]
```

The problem is my website images are protected all right, but when I want to access the `index.php` from a parent directory (the htaccess is in my subdirectory, not the parent), I am shown a `403 Forbidden` error.

Now I am not really clear as to what these lines mean, or how to tweak them, so I can't tell right from wrong. Can someone help me out and tell what this actually does? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either your assets are accessible or they're not. You cannot serve assets to the public without serving them publicly. You probably think "from localhost" means if someone is "on your website" already; that's a wrong understanding of how the web works. Every asset is requested from the server via a URL, all requests come from clients. Requests do not come from "your local website".

If endusers must be able to see your assets, they must be able to access them via a URL, which means they'll also be able to see them when "inputting the URL directly". There's no technical difference there.

Comment: Does that mean I won't be able to prevent them from accessing some assets even if they're not logged in?

Comment: No, you can authorize every request individually, including requests to asset files. However, if you're managing your authorization in PHP, you'll have to proxy all requests through PHP. E.g. `/getasset.php?file=foo.css`.